# Bootstrap columns are stacking instead of staying in line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.7.7 and I'm trying to figure out why my 3 columns are stacking like this at full width instead of staying inline in one row. They should be staying in a full line until the screen gets down to small size, but they automatically start out stacked like this, and I can't figure out why:

[image]

```
        <div class="container-fluid" id="currentTools">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1 currentToolsCol" id="toolbarColumn">
                // toolbar with dropdowns here
                </div>
                    <!--Tables and Animals viewspace -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 currentToolsCol" id="projectdataColumn">
                    <h2 class="viewHeader">Project Data</h2>
                    <hr class="viewHeaderHR">

                </div>
                    <!-- Notes viewspace -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-11 sliderContainer currentToolsCol" id="notesColumn">
                    <h2 class="sliderHeaderRow" id="notesHeader">Notes</h2>
                    <div class="appSliders" id="workspaceNoteSlider">
                        <i class="fa fa-book sliderMainbutton" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <h3>View Project Notes</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appSliderContent container-fluid " id="notesLoadZone" url='@routes.ProjectsWorkSpaceController.getAllNotes(projectTitle)'>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I've made a JFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1jbyxouo/), but it's not quite representative of what's happening due to things getting stored locally and there needing to be some server stuff executing to get this to execute properly.

I've noticed I can "fix" this if I set the middle element to be at a width of 45% instead of its manual 50%, but that seems to be over-complicating it when the Bootstrap should be taking care of this.

Shouldn't the Bootstrap grid be keeping these things in line?

Comment: You're probably viewing it at the `col-sm` size, at that breakpoint, it will use the same layout as `col-xs` because you haven't defined the column sizes for `sm`. The layout is 3 columns at the `md` breakpoint and higher based on the code you provided: https://www.bootply.com/ZY0PoQvnX4

Comment: I've tried setting them as such:
`<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 currentToolsCol" id="toolbarColumn">`
`<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-11 currentToolsCol" id="projectdataColumn">`
`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-10 col-xs-11 sliderContainer currentToolsCol" id="notesColumn">`
But the same issue is still occurring.

Comment: The layout is correct based on the code you provided, you can see in the example I provided above that it is in 3 columns, there must be some other issue with your code.

Comment: Hmm... thank you. When I don't put any margin between them, it's fine, but the minute I do to separate them out a bit, then they stack. I need the margin though. should I manually adjust their widths? Seems tedious and risk of "different results for different screen sizes"

Comment: Use padding instead of margin if you want to add more space. Adding margin will break the bootstrap columns.

Comment: Got it, did try that, but it just pushed the contents of the boxes inward, but the borders remained intact and in place, without putting space between the boxes like I'd hoped. I'm guessing this means I should nest everything down into one div further from the column div.